# Error al ingresar el precio en la base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al llenar el formulario brinda el error mostrado en la imagen, añade toda la informacion menos el apartado donde dice precio por unidad, los demas datos si los añade a la base de datos, nose porque si hice todo igual, el error de la imagen es la linea donde declare la variable de precio ayuda porfavor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        
        <script>
            function limpiar(){
                document.getElementById('codigo').value = '';
                document.getElementById('categoria').selectedIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('nombre_material').value = '';
                document.getElementById('unidad').selectedIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('cantidad').value = '';
                document.getElementById('minimo').value = '';
                document.getElementById('precio').value = 0 ;
                document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML="";   
                document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje2').innerHTML="";    
            }
        </script>
        
        
        <script>
            function insertar_material(){
        var 
        //From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
      //emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      
      codigo = $("#codigo"),
      categoria = $("#categoria"),
      nombre_material = $( "#nombre_material"),
      factura = $("#numero_factura"),
      unidad = $("#unidad"),      
      cantidad = $("#cantidad"),
      mini = $("#minimo"),
      prec = $("#precio"),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( codigo ).add( categoria ).add( nombre_material ).add( unidad ).add( cantidad ).add( mini ).add( prec );   
     
        
        var div = String(document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML);
        var dib = String(document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje2').innerHTML);
       //var div1 = '<img alt="" src="http://localhost/sistema_mantenimiento/recursos/img/no.png" height="6%" width="6%">Ocupado.';
       var div1 = div.search('Ocupado.');
       var div2 = dib.search('Ocupado.');
        //alert(div1);
        if (div1 != -1 || div2 != -1 ){
            alert("Debe seleccionar un nombre y código válido.");    
                 
            var valid = false;
        }
        else{            
            var valid = true;
        }
      
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            
      codigo = $("#codigo"),
      categoria = $("#categoria"),
      nombre_material = $( "#nombre_material"),
      unidad = $("#unidad"),      
      cantidad = $("#cantidad"),
      mini   = $("#minimo"),
      prec   = $("#precio"),
      
      valid = valid && checkLength( codigo, "Código", 8, 8 );       
      //valid = valid && checkLength( categoria, "Categoría", 3, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( nombre_material, "Nombre de Material", 3, 250 );
      //valid = valid && checkLength( unidad, "Unidad", 1, 3 );      
      valid = valid && checkLength( cantidad, "Cantidad", 1, 6 );     
      
    //  valid = valid && checkRegexp( codigo, /^([0-9\s])+$/i, "El código debe de estar compuesto solo por números.");
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( nombre_material, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/i, "El Nombre debe de estar compuesto solo por letras y numeros." );
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( cantidad, /^([0-9\s])+$/i, "La cantidad desde contener solo números.");
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( usuario, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "El nombre de usuario puede contener solo letras y números" );
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( pass, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "La contraseña solo permite letras y números");
 
      if (valid){   
          // document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML="<img src='http://localhost/sistema_mantenimiento/recursos/img/loading.gif' height='6%' width='6%' alt='' />";
          if ( document.getElementById('categoria').selectedIndex ==0 ||  
                  document.getElementById('unidad').selectedIndex == 0)
          {
              alert('Debe seleccionar una categoría y una unidad de la lista');
          }
          else
          {             
          
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',              
              url: 'formularios/ins_material.php', 
                        data: {codigo: codigo.val(), categoria: categoria.val(),
                            nombre: nombre_material.val().toLowerCase(), nfactura: factura.val(), unidad: unidad.val(), 
                            cantidad: cantidad.val(), min: mini.val()},
              error: function(){
                  alert("error petición ajax");
              },
              success: function(data){                                                      
                      if (confirm(data + "\n ¿Desea insertar un nuevo material?") === true) {                       
                       $("#contenido").load("formularios/frm_new_material.php/?accion=");
                       document.getElementById('codigo').value = '';
                document.getElementById('categoria').selectedIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('nombre_material').value = '';
                 document.getElementById('unidad').selectedIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('cantidad').value = '';
                document.getElementById('minimo').value = '';
                document.getElementById('precio').value = 0 ;
                document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML="";   
                document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje2').innerHTML="";                  
                   } 
                   else {
                    $( "#contenido" ).empty();
                    $( "#contenido2" ).empty();
                    document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML="<img src='http://localhost/sistema_mantenimiento/recursos/img/loading.gif' height='6%' width='6%' alt='' />";
                    $("#contenido").load("formularios/frm_listar_materiales.php");
                   }   
              }
              });  
              }
               
      }
      return valid;                            
     }
        </script>
        
        
        
         <script>
            function editar_material(id){
        var modificado,
    codigo = $("#codigo"),
      categoria = $("#categoria"),
      nombre_material = $( "#nombre_material"),
      unidad = $("#unidad"),      
      cantidad = $("#cantidad"),
      cantidado = $("#cantidado"),
      mini = $("#minimo"),
      prec = $("#precio"),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( codigo ).add( categoria ).add( nombre_material ).add( unidad ).add( cantidad ).add( mini ).add( prec ); 
          
     
 
     var div = String(document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML);
     var dib = String(document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje2').innerHTML);
       //var div1 = '<img alt="" src="http://localhost/sistema_mantenimiento/recursos/img/no.png" height="6%" width="6%">Ocupado.';
       var div1 = div.search('Ocupado.');
       var div2 = dib.search('Ocupado.');
        //alert(div1);
        if (div1 != -1 || div2 != -1 ){
            alert("Debe seleccionar un nombre y código válido.");    
                 
            var valid = false;
        }
        else{            
            var valid = true;
        }
      
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      
      codigo = $("#codigo"),
      categoria = $("#categoria"),
      nombre_material = $( "#nombre_material"),
      unidad = $("#unidad"),      
      cantidad = $("#cantidad"),
      mini = $("#minimo"),
      prec = $("#precio"),
 
      valid = valid && checkLength( codigo, "Código", 8, 8 );       
      //valid = valid && checkLength( categoria, "Categoría", 3, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( nombre_material, "Nombre de Material", 3, 250 );
      //valid = valid && checkLength( unidad, "Unidad", 1, 3 );      
      valid = valid && checkLength( cantidad, "Cantidad", 1, 6 );     
      
    //  valid = valid && checkRegexp( codigo, /^([0-9\s])+$/i, "El código debe de estar compuesto solo por números.");
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( nombre_material, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/i, "El Nombre debe de estar compuesto solo por letras y numeros." );
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( cantidad, /^([0-9\s])+$/i, "La cantidad desde contener solo números.");
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( usuario, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "El nombre de usuario puede contener solo letras y números" );
     // valid = valid && checkRegexp( pass, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "La contraseña solo permite letras y números");lo letras y números" );
     
 
      if (valid){   
          if ( document.getElementById('categoria').selectedIndex ==0 ||  
                  document.getElementById('unidad').selectedIndex == 0)
          {
              alert('Debe seleccionar una categoría y una unidad de la lista');
          }
          else
          {  
          modificado = 'SI';
          if (parseInt(cantidado.val()) == parseInt(cantidad.val())){
              modificado = 'NO';
          }
          // document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML="<img src='http://localhost/sistema_mantenimiento/recursos/img/loading.gif' height='6%' width='6%' alt='' />";
           
          if (confirm(" ¿Desea modificar la información del material? \n" + codigo.val() ) === true) {                       
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'formularios/editar_material.php', 
                        data: {ide: id, codigo: codigo.val(), categoria: categoria.val(),
                            nombre: nombre_material.val().toLowerCase(), unidad: unidad.val(), 
                            cantidad: cantidad.val(), min: mini.val(), prec: prec.val(), modi: modificado},            
                        dataType: "html",
                        error: function(data){
                            alert("error petición ajax");
                        },
                        success: function(data){                                                      
                            alert(data);         
                            $("#contenido").load("formularios/frm_listar_materiales.php");
                        }
                    });  
                   } 
                   else {                   
                   }                      
      }
      return valid;     
      }
     }
        </script>
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <?php
        // put your code here
       require_once 'conexion.php';
            
       $codigo = "";
       $categoria ="";
       $nombre_material ="";
       $unidad ="";
       $cantidad ="";
       $mini = "";
       $prec = "";
       $accion = $_GET['accion'];
       $var1 = substr($accion,0,6);
       $var2 = substr($accion,6,17);
       $tipo_insercion = "insertar_material()";
            
        if ( $var1 == "editar"){
            echo "<h3 align=center>
                EDITAR MATERIAL
            </h3>";          
            
            $tipo_insercion = "editar_material(".$var2.")";
         
            
            $sql = "SELECT idmaterial, codigo, categoria, nombre_material,"
                . " unidad, cantidad, minimo, precio  FROM material WHERE idmaterial=".$var2;           
                              
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);     
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {  
                              
            $codigo = $rows[1];
            $categoria = $rows[2];
            $nombre_material = $rows[3];
            $unidad = $rows[4];
            $cantidad = $rows[5];
            $mini = $rows[6];
            $prec = $rows[7];
            }
                                  
        
        }
        else{
            echo "<h3 align=center>
                NUEVO MATERIAL
            </h3>";           
            
        }
        ?>
        
        <form id="myform" action="" class="dark-matter" >
            <h1>
                <span class="validateTips">Todos los campos son requeridos</span>
            </h1>
            <label>
                <span>Código:</span>
                <input type="text" name="codigo" maxlength="8" size="15" id="codigo" placeholder="Escriba aquí" value="<?php echo"$codigo" ?>" 
                       onchange="comprobar_campo(this.value, 'material', 'codigo', 'comprobar_mensaje' )" required>      
            </label>
             <div  id="comprobar_mensaje"></div>
             <label>
               <span>Categoría:</span>
               <select name="categoria"  id="categoria" required> 
                  <?php   
                  $row;
                  $sql = "SELECT idcategoria, categoria FROM categoria";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);       
                
                  echo'<option value="#">--Seleccione una opción--</option>';
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 
                      if($categoria == $row[0]){
                          echo '<option value='.$row[0].' selected>'. strtoupper(utf8_encode($row[1])).'</option> \n';   
                      }
                      else{
                          echo '<option value='.$row[0].'>'.strtoupper(utf8_encode($row[1])).'</option> \n';   
                      }
                      
                      }             
               $sql = "";
               $result = "";
               ?> 
                    </select>    
            </label> 
            <label>
                <span>Nombre de Material:</span>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_material" size="15" id="nombre_material" placeholder="Escriba aquí" 
                       value="<?php echo utf8_encode($nombre_material) ?>"
                      onchange="comprobar_campo(this.value, 'material', 'nombre_material', 'comprobar_mensaje2' )" required >    
            </label>           
                <div  id="comprobar_mensaje2"></div>
            
            <?php
                if ($var1 == 'editar'){
                    echo "<label hidden>
                          <span hidden> No. Factura:</span>
                          <input  hidden type=text name=numero_factura maxlength='10' placeholder='Escriba aquí'  id='numero_factura' />      
                          </label> ";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<label>
                          <span > No. Factura:</span>
                          <input type=text name=numero_factura maxlength='10' placeholder='Escriba aquí' id='numero_factura'  required>      
                          </label> ";
                }
            ?>
            
                
            <label>
               <span>Unidad de Medida:</span>
               <select name="unidad"  id="unidad" required> 
                  <?php   
                  $row;
                  $sql = "SELECT idunidad_medida, unidad FROM unidad_medida";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);                
                  //echo '<select name="privi"  id="privi" required>';
                  echo'<option value="#">--Seleccione una opción--</option>';
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 
                      if($unidad == $row[0]){
                          echo '<option value='.$row[0].' selected>'.$row[1].'</option> \n';   
                      }
                      else{
                          echo '<option value='.$row[0].'>'.$row[1].'</option> \n';   
                      }
                      
                      }                                                                      
               //echo "</select>";     
               $sql = "";
               $result = "";
               ?> 
                    </select>    
            </label>
            
            <label>
                <span>Cantidad:</span>
                <input type="number" name="cantidad" size="15" id="cantidad" value="<?php echo"$cantidad" ?>" min="1" max="9999" placeholder="Escriba aquí" required />                                
                <input  hidden type="number" name="cantidado" size="15" id="cantidado" value="<?php echo"$cantidad" ?>" min="1" max="9999" placeholder="0" required />                                
            </label>                 
                <br>
                <br>
            <label>
                <span>Mínimo de unidades:</span>
                <input type="number" name="minimo" size="15" id="minimo" value="<?php echo"$mini" ?>" min="1" max="9999" placeholder="Escriba aquí" required />                                
            </label> 
                <br>
                <br>
            <label>
                <span>Precio por unidad:</span>
                <input type="number" name="precio" size="15" id="precio" value="<?php echo"$prec" ?>" min="1" max="9999" placeholder="Escriba aquí" required />                                
                <input  hidden type="number" name="precio" size="15" id="precio" value="<?php echo"$prec" ?>" min="1" max="9999" placeholder="0" required />                                
            </label>
            <!--<input type="button" class="button" value="Regresar" onclick="cargar_nuevo('frm_listar_materiales')" > -->
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Guardar" onclick="<?php echo"$tipo_insercion" ?>" >     
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiar()">
            </form>
            <br>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
require 'conexion.php';
session_start(); 
 
$cod=$_POST['codigo']; 
$cat=$_POST['categoria']; 
$nombr=strtolower(utf8_decode($_POST['nombre'])); 
$unida=$_POST['unidad']; 
$cant= $_POST['cantidad']; 
$min= $_POST['min'];  
$prec = $_POST['precio']; 
$n_factura = $_POST['nfactura'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i');

 $log_error = "";
$sql0 = [];
 
$usuario_conectado = $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];
//$pass = md5($pass);

         
            if (!$conexion){       
               echo "hay conexion ". mysqli_connect_error();    
               }
            else{
                $sql1 = "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0";
                $res1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql1);
                
                $sql2 = "BEGIN;";
                $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
                //echo 'se ha conectado ';                                       
                $sql3 = "INSERT INTO material (codigo, categoria, nombre_material, unidad, cantidad, minimo, precio)"
                        . "VALUES ( '$cod','$cat', '$nombr', '$unida', '$cant', '$min', '$prec' )"; 
                
                $res3 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql3);               

                 if ($res3 !== true){
                    $log_error .= "\n - Problema al insertar el material debido al error: ". mysqli_error($conexion);
                    } 
                    
               $sql4  = "INSERT INTO movimientos (fecha, num_factura, codigo_material, cantidad, tipo_movimiento, saldo, retira) "
                       . "VALUES ( '$fecha', '$n_factura', '$cod',"
                       . " '$cant', 'ENTRADA', '$cant','$usuario_conectado' )";                   
              $res4 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql4);    
                        
                   if ($res4 !== true){
                       $log_error .= "\n - No se ha podiddo grabar la salida del material número: ".$codigos[$i]." debido al error: ". mysqli_error($conexion);
                           }    
                                          
               if (($res1 == true) && ($res2 == true) && ($res3 == true) && ($res4 == true)) {
                           echo 'Se ha insertado correctamente el material No.:'.$cod  ;
                           echo '';
                           $sql0 = "COMMIT";
                           $res0 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql0);                          
                       }
                       else
                           {                          
                           //echo $log_error;
                           echo ' ';
                           echo 'Se han encontrado los siguientes errores durante la ejecucion: ';  
                           echo "\n" ;
                           echo $log_error;
                           $sql0 = "ROLLBACK;";                           
                           }                 
            }
            $sql = "";
            mysqli_close($conexion);             
?>
```

Comment: la variable precio no la veo en el data de tu ajax, ese es el error porque al querer guardar en tu base de datos la variabe no se encuentra

Comment: rectifico, si va, pero la mandas con el nombre prec: prec.val(), y aqui no coincide $prec = $_POST['precio'];

Comment: y como tendria que ir?

Comment: Las validaciones de contenido están para que describas con detalle suficiente tu regunta, no para que copies y pegues el mismo texto N veces. Si te pide más detalle, es porque seguramente faltan detalles ;)

Comment: @LuisAngel $prec = $_POST['precio'] cambia esto por esto $prec = $_POST['prec'] y prueba

Comment: @HeynerMartinez ponlo como respuesta, no como comentario :)

Comment: Debes de cambiar esto en tu archivo $prec = $_POST['precio'] por esto $prec = $_POST['prec'], solo es problema de renombrado de tu variable

Comment: cierto, gracias :P

Comment: siempre aparece el mismo error

Comment: ese era el único error que logre detectar, es un poco complicado sin poder ir depurando

Comment: muchas gracas bro